# Div container with text on the left side and overflow image on the right

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, grid

I want to recreate the following structure: [image]

With black is div container and inside the container on the left there will be text and on the right i need an image bigger than the container.

I tried to do this by grids but things got funky real quick.

Comment: Please could you show us the code that you have tried - and in particular we need to see the structure of your HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems to be important that the containing div maintains the dimensions (as shown by its border), this snippet adds in the actual image as a background on a pseudo element that is absolutely positioned.

That way the protruding bit of image does  not alter the container div dimensions.

Here's a simple snippet using a grid to position the left and right sides. Of course you will want to alter proportions to suit your particular case, add styling to the leftside and so on:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr;
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

.leftside {
  padding: 1vw;
}

.rightside {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightside::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: pink;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/500/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 140%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftside">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>text1</div>
    <div>text2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
.background {
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img>div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="text">
    <p>
      text1
    </p>
    <p>
      text2
    </p>
    <button>
 Click me
 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <div>
      me img
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please put code into your answer rather than on an outside site. This is so that future readers will be able to see it even if the outside site disappears.

Comment: Oh okay, I am sorry, will do. Thx for the tip @AHaworth

Answer (score 1):

go with the flexbox.

```css
.main-container{
  display:flex;
      display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:30px;
  height:300px;
   padding:10px;
}
.image{
  width:50vw;
  position:relative;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
  width: 100%;
    height: 150%;
    top: -50%;
    position: absolute;
}
.text{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Somthing Somthing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" />
  </div>
</div>
```